# Kill -9 -1 behaviour on MacOS

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, operating-system

Our teachers told us to experiment with the terminal and `kill -9 -1` 
To my understanding, on UNIX based OS, the first process charged is Init with PID -1 from which the other processes will spawn. I assumed that you couldn't kill it as it is charged in a secured part of memory.

On a VM running LinuxMint, the command would would cause the session to close itself. On MacOS, it would close/crahs(?) all applications.

On some other people laptops running different distribution of Linux the command would be denied which was the behaviour I would have expected in any OS.

So I am confused by the behaviour of the command.
What should be the normal result? Or is it bound to each OS implementation?

Thanks.

Comment: Process ID of Init is 1 not -1

Answer (score 0):

The general behaviour, from [Kill MAN page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html#DESCRIPTION):

```
If pid equals -1, then sig is sent to every process for which the calling process has permission to send signals, except for process 1 (init)
```

So, "kill -9 -1" will kill all processes it can.